# Responsive PayPal Subscription Checkout?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

**About 90%+ of my website users are using the mobile page.** I offer a monthly membership subscription plan and just build the PayPal subscription form with PHP.

After all data is sent, it opens up the PayPal page and this big image appears in a tiny on Smartphone version, because it isn't responsive like the rest of my website:

[image]

Normal payments are responsive but subscriptions are not. I offer other payment services like GoCardless but need to offer the PayPal solution too. Many users would get confused and cancel the payment.

However, I kept searching for other solutions for some days now and there is this JavaScript option available: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/button.md

This opens up a popup on my site and it seems like to be the solution but I couldn't find an option for subscriptions also.

What alternatives do I have or did I overlook something? I just need a responsive solution for PayPal subscriptions to get monthly payments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to do recurring subscriptions in my Django and the frontend team complained that the paypal checkout page is not responsive, and they have a point. It seems incredible that today with all the subscription based services (Netflix, Spotify, Microsoft Office, PS Plus, etc . . . ) PayPal (one of the worldwide 'digital wallets' ) still isn't responsive wth all that.

It's curios because the express checkout and the one time pay page are all changed.

I found this article that said they will do changes to that part 
[Upcoming Change to PayPal Subscriptions](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-HTML-Buttons/Upcoming-Change-to-PayPal-Subscriptions/m-p/1390212)

Well with all this the problem it's still unresolved and hopping they will do something about this.